# Hive query to group

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, hive, beehive

I have the following table columns: ID (id), Type (string. could be either: open or close)

I would like to get an output count where for each unique ID, I count how many times the ID got the open type and how many times it got the close type.

So the output would look like this:

```
ID | openCount | closeCount
10 | 23        | 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

select ID,count( * ) AS "openCount" where type = "open" group by ID union select ID,count( * ) AS "closeCount" where type = "close" group by ID;

that should do it. it's count(star) stack overflow doesn't seem to like that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, SUM(type='open') openCount, SUM(type='closed') closedCount FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

What happens is that the SUM() function aggregates all `type='open'` and `type='closed'` values for all rows which share the same `id` value, which if true is `1` and if false is `0`.